# Want to Redirect My HTML page to Homepage of Website

Tags: php, html, css, themes, custom-wordpress-pages

I have Created a HTML page for my wordpress website homepage and now i want to redirect that HTML page to my website homepage.
The page is already uploaded to my wordpress folder root directory

Comment: Or if Cannot be Redirected Suggest me another way thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is this related to CSS or the concept of themes?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to redirect from `new.html` page to `wordpress` `index.php` file:

Redirect using `PHP`:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Redirect using `HTML Meta`:

```
<meta http-equiv = "refresh" content = "2; url = https://www.example.com" />
```

Redirect using `Javascript`:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use meta refresh attribute to redirect to a different site.

(content="0; will do an immediate redirect.)

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your html page meta tag to redirect to your website

```
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv = "refresh" content = "1; url = https://www.yoursite.com" />
</head>
```